# Call legacy Win32 API from C++/Winrt UWP app

Tags: c++-winrt

Is it possible call a legacy Win32 API from a UWP app written using C++/WinRT? I'm trying to call a legacy API from BluetoothApis.h.

Is this possible? App is a pure desktop app. Tks.

Comment: *"Desktop app"* and *"UWP app"* are mutually exclusive. Which platform are you targeting? This is the deciding factor in determining availability of any particular API. C++/WinRT is a library, that can be used to target either platform.

Comment: Targeting Windows !0. Love WinRT for its beautifully abstracted API. But would like to use the legacy BluetoothRemoveDevice API to get avoid the confirmation prompt while unpairing a device.

Comment: Windows 10 can run UWP apps as well as Desktop apps. Which application type are you targeting? The title says *"UWP app"*, but the question says *"App is a pure desktop app"*. Those are mutually exclusive, and you need to explain, what platform you are targeting to make this question answerable.

Answer (score 2):

The only Win32 APIs that are supported from a UWP app are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps).

All other Win32 legacy APIs are not available, which means:

- The `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` macros in the headers won't define the declaration for those unsupported functions, so use of them will result in a compile-time error.
- If you tried to use one of those legacy Win32 APIs anyway, then when you submitted to the Windows Store the WACK tool would detect it and fail the application.
- If you try to run the unsupported UWP app on some other Device Family than Desktop (i.e. Xbox One), those legacy Win32 imports will likely be missing.

If you misconfigure the `WINAPI_FAMILY` macro or locally declare unsupported functions, only-side load because you never try to submit to the Store, and only attempt to run it on a Desktop PC, then the function may or may not work anyhow. It depends on how the Win32 legacy function reacts to the restricted ACLs of the AppContainer process context that all UWPs run in.

**TL;DR:** No, you can't use BluetoothAPis.h in a UWP app

```
#pragma region Desktop Family
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)

.. all functions and types in BluetoothApis.h are here...

#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */
#pragma endregion
```